# Can I seperate comments from post?

Tags: comments

I have a type of attachments that need full screen display. So, I need to put the comments form somewhere else. How can I tell WP those comments belongs to a post?

Comment: looking forward to this question's answer... no idea. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most starter themes now, like [Twenty Eleven](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyeleven), come with separate files for each template — for example, `single.php` and `content-single.php` represent the *Single* (Post) template in Twenty Eleven.

The starter theme I use, [Reddle](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/reddle/) ([ddl](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/reddle/1.0)), has the same template hierarchy, and here's the solution I am using...

1. **Create a blank Page** (NOT Post) titled "Comments, Questions and Feedback" or something of your choice. Leave the body blank, and publish the page.
2. Make a copy of `single.php` and rename it to `page-comments.php` (where "comments" in page-**comments**.php is the slug of the Page we created above).

   **(A)** In it, replace this:

   ```
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   <?php
       $p = $_GET['u'];
       $the_query = new WP_Query("showposts=1&p=" . $p);
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
   ?>
   ```

   **(B)** Also replace this:

   ```
   <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'comments' ); ?>
   ```
3. Make a copy of `content-single.php` and rename it to `content-comments.php` (in content-**comments**.php "comments" should be the same as the parameter you use in `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'comments' ); ?>` as shown above **2(B)**).

   Now depending on what content you want to show on the standalone Comments page, edit out all the code in the template. For example, the first thing you might want to remove is the code that outputs the post's content.

   For example, [this is the original `content-single.php`](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/reddle/1.0/content-single.php) of my theme, and after editing out all the unnecessary code (that I didn't want to show on the Comments page), this is what is left in the file:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * The default template for displaying post comments.
    *
    * @package Reddle
    * @since Reddle 1.0
    */
   ?>

   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
       <header class="entry-header">
           <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'reddle' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

           <?php if ( comments_open() || ( '0' != get_comments_number() && ! comments_open() ) ) : ?>
           <p class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="no-reply">' . __( '0', 'reddle' ) . '</span>', __( '1', 'reddle' ), __( '%', 'reddle' ) ); ?></p>
           <?php endif; ?>
       </header><!-- .entry-header -->
   </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
   ```
4. Add a rewrite rule to your .htaccess file to make the URL to the Comments page pretty:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^comments/([0-9]+)/?$ /comments/?u=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

   Now, the Comments page for a post would be `http://example.com/comments/17/` if `17` is its post ID.
5. How will your readers know where to leave comments unless you link to the comments page? So, in your `content-single.php` or any template appropriate to you (depending on where you want to show the link), use this code:

   ```
   <a href="/comments/<?php the_ID(); ?>/">Leave A Comment!</a>
   ```

It's really simple, and there's no additional CSS involved as your comments pages inherit the same template as your posts. Yes, I did try this before sharing the answer here. It worked like a charm!

### SCREENSHOTS

*(Rough but working...)*

[image: Screenshot]

---

*Based on "[Provide a Better Reading Experience in your WordPress Blog](http://www.labnol.org/internet/wordpress-reading-experience/19845/)" by Amit Agarwal.*

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat complex in that several things need to be done in order for it to work. I suggest you write this as a plugin instead of dumping it into your theme.

First thing you will need are the actual post comments, you have two options here:

1. `get_comments`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments
2. `wp_list_comments`  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Both will need to be passed the post ID, I would suggest making a callback function for `wp_list_comments`.

You will also need to use another function called `comment_form` to render the input for making actual comments. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

Input and output of the comments is straightforward, the challenge is creating a relationship between the post and the separate comment form/display so that the user can easy navigate back and forth. I recommend reading MikeSchinkel's answer in this post to accomplish that
[Linking to Page Showing Only Comments Without Parent Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277/linking-to-page-showing-only-comments-without-parent-post?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the way! I will study MikeSchinkel's solution.

Answer (score -2):

What about a tabbed post page, just like reuters.com. You can use pure css or ajax and separate the post content from comments visually.

Comment: reuters.com is seperated. the post's URL is http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/06/29/us-eurozone-idUSBRE85O0CS20120629 , and the comment's URL is http://www.reuters.com/article/comments/idUSBRE85O0CS20120629. So, they are not just tabbed, but they are on different page.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying visually.

Comment: A WordPress with separate comments from post content is DePoMasthead (love this theme!), you can download and try to work from there https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/depo-masthead/