# if/else on custom query gives 200 OK when condition not met?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, 404-error, headers

**What?** I am modifying my theme to show comments of a post on a separate page.

**How?** Mostly [based on this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57161/10691) but with improved checks and code. So this is what my page-comments.php (kinda) looks like:

**(The code is very easy to scan through, trust me!)**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    /*
     * (Example URL: example.com/comments/?original_post=ID)
     *
     * Check if HTTP variable (original_post) exists in queried URL,
     * AND that it is set to some value (ID), AND that the value (ID) is a number.
     */
    if( array_key_exists( 'original_post', $_GET ) && isset( $_GET['original_post'] ) && ctype_digit( $_GET['original_post'] ) ) {

        $query_original_post = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'p'              => $_GET['original_post'],
            'post_type'      => 'any',
        ) );

        if( $query_original_post->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $query_original_post->have_posts() ) : $query_original_post->the_post();

                // [...]

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

        } else {

            /*
             * Return 404 error if there are no posts
             */
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
            nocache_headers();
            get_template_part( '404', 'archive' );
            //exit();

        }

    } else {

        /*
         * Return 404 error if the HTTP variable (original_post) doesn't
         * exist in queried URL, OR it isn't set to any value (ID),
         * OR the value (ID) isn't a number.
         */
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        nocache_headers();
        get_template_part( '404', 'archive' );
        //exit();

    }
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

*(The code I use to return a 404 error is based on [these two](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92176) [solutions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27124).)*

As you can see I am doing two checks in the code (**at least that's what I intended to do**):

1. Check if HTTP variable (original_post) exists in queried URL, AND that it is set to some value (ID), AND that the value (ID) is a number. OTHERWISE, return a 404 error with appropriate headers.
2. Check if the custom WordPress query (`$query_original_post`) has any results to loop over. OTHERWISE, return a 404 error with appropriate headers.

**Problem:**

1. Is that the right way to do it? (or at least, can it be any simpler?)
2. *(If yes to #1)* It appears to work, but returns 200 OK header when I go to an URL like: `example.com/comments/?original_post=NUMBER`, where NUMBER is any positive integer over 4 digits long (e.g. 14532).

   I don't understand the relation. Why'd something like ``example.com/comments/?original_post=14532` return 200 OK header when I am logged-into WordPress, and 404 error (which it should) when I am not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers are sent long before you try to alter them. Headers are sent by actions associated with `get_header()`, so by the time your code executes, it is too late to alter the headers. You can demonstrate this with a simple experiment. Try each of the following:

```
get_header(); 
status_header( 404 );
```

and

```
status_header( 404 );
get_header();
```

In a template file and watch the output with a tool like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (if you *really* want to have some fun :) ).

To effectively change the headers you will need to run your logic *before* `get_header()`.

I believe this will get the effect you want with fewer lines of code to boot:

```
/*
* (Example URL: example.com/comments/?original_post=ID)
*
* Check if HTTP variable (original_post) exists in queried URL,
* AND that it is set to some value (ID), AND that the value (ID) is a number.
*/

if( 
  array_key_exists( 'original_post', $_GET ) 
  && isset( $_GET['original_post'] ) 
  && ctype_digit( $_GET['original_post'] ) 
) {
  $query_original_post = new WP_Query( 
    array(
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'p'              => $_GET['original_post'],
      'post_type'      => 'any',
    ) 
  );
  if( !$query_original_post->have_posts() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
  } 
}

get_header();
if( !empty($query_original_post) && $query_original_post->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query_original_post->have_posts() ) {
    $query_original_post->the_post();
    // [...]
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
  get_template_part( '404', 'archive' );
}
get_footer();
```

And for the love of all that is holy please don't use PHP opening and closing tags unless you actually need them.

Comment: Had no clue the order matters. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation (and the clean code)!

Comment: Most cases order does matter. PHP does not compile and then execute. It executes as it goes.