# Separated Comment from Post

Tags: theme-development, comments

I'm designer with little knowledge of wordpress (newbie >_<)

i use  Worpress starter theme from : html5blank.com

i want to separate **COMMENT** section from **POST** section, this still on one single.php page. I have look [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52275/can-i-seperate-comments-from-post)  but didnt worked for me ( look like because theme hirarcy of  Twenty Eleven and my theme (html5blank) diferent ),

here the design of the web : https://plus.google.com/110670554739072533922/posts/B2erhKgkZVc

- POST section
- Related Post section
- **Comment section ---> (1) i want to separated this**

Comment: @toscho im new to wordpress and stackexchange, thankyou for the revisionn, (1) its ok u remove word "wordpress" on title and <wordpress.org> tag. (2) but what i dont know why u remove "thankyou :)" from my question. is it wrong to express "thanks" to other ?

Comment: im going to try edit the css to disguise the visual using : start LOOP <post> <related post> <comment> /end LOOP.

Comment: Salutations are seen as "noise" here, we like to scan posts as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahaaa :D
it's success, I use CSS.
Here the screenshot [image: Separated comment from post page]

the code i use on **single.php** :

```
<!-- post section -->
<section class="post-section all-round grid">
    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end .post-section -->

<!-- comment section -->
<section class="comment-section all-round grid">
    <?php if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) : ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>
<!-- end .comment-section -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

**CSS code :**

```
/* SECTION TO SEPARATE POST AND COMMENT */

.post-section, .comment-section  {
    background-color: white;
    width: 900px;
    margin:20px auto;
}
```

the schema :

- LOOP
- < Post >
- < Comment Section  >
- END LOOP